# PHP conditional IF statement to display HTML form

Tags: php

I want to only display a form if the author of a post is not the current user. However, the below code displays the html form regardless of the condition in the IF statement being met or not. Is this perhaps not a valid way to run conditional HTML code with php?

```
<?php
//The form, only displayed on condition

if($author !== $user_ID)
{
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Contact</button>
<input type="hidden" name="contact" value="<?php echo $CID; ?>">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: this code seems to be okay. What is in `$author` and `$user_ID`? Try to `var_dump` them. You compare by `!==`, so if one of them is number, the second one string, it returns false. `2 == '2'` but `2 !== '2'`.

Comment: maybe $author is a string (eg. "1") and $useR_ID is a int (1). try casting into int or use  !=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use != instead of !==

```
<?php
//The form, only displayed on condition

if($author != $user_ID)
{
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<button type="submit">Contact</button>
<input type="hidden" name="contact" value="<?php echo $CID; ?>">
</form>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why he'd use `!=` instead of `!==`.

Comment: != will not match the datatype of the value. In that case 1 != '1' will also return false

Comment: That's it. I thought !== was the same thing but also allowed you not to need to declare a type. In any case, my values are both INT so != works fine and executed the code conditionally correctly. Thanks.